Zend Equivalent class for Magento 2.4.6
We have updated our website to Magento 2.4.6.
We are facing Zend issue with the following
1.Zend_Pdf
pdf = new Zend_Pdf();
$page = new Zend_Pdf_Page(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
//var_dump($page);
  

2.Zend_Log_Exception
Can anyone please tell the equivalent class for the above.
Thanks,
Jayashree

have you tries new \Zend_Pdf(); instaed of new Zend_Pdf(); ? and have a look at vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php

In Magento 2.4.6, the Zend Framework has been removed

Just replace Zend_Pdf by \Zend_Pdf and Zend_Pdf_Page by \Zend_Pdf_Page
They have migrated to Laminas but there are still some Zend libraries, such as Zend PDF
